# Can I use a Regular Expression to prevent editing?

Tags: regex, google-forms, editing

I am using Google forms with regular expressions in various text fields. I want to send people a variety of pre-filled forms with a field that directs their response to an appropriate destination. It is critical that the form completer doesn't change the pre-filled answer, but there is no way of hiding that field from the user. Is there any way of setting a regex to fix the first entry in a field (ie my pre-filled entry) and prevent it from being edited?

Comment: [What about this?](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FW5GS8OODAI0)

Comment: @rv7 `disabled` won't submit the value. `readonly` will.